# The click does not work at every iteration. How to make the click work in a loop?

Tags: javascript

I am just starting to learn JS.

```js
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}

for (var j = 1; j < 1000; j++) {
  var input = document.querySelectorAll('[data]');
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
   input[i].click();
   console.log(i)
   sleep(158)
}}
```

In this code, the `click()` is made after the end of the loop for all elements. How can I fix the code so that the `click()` is triggered on every iteration?

Comment: That is absolutely not how to "sleep" in JavaScript. What that function does primarily is make client computers get hot.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it doesn't work is because you are halting the whole process for your browser. It has no time to execute the event listeners if you fill it with endless work. You should use async/await to sleep instead.

```
async function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, ms);
    })
}

for (var j = 1; j < 1000; j++) {
    var input = document.querySelectorAll('[data]');
    for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
       input[i].click();
       console.log(i)
       await sleep(158);
    }
}
```

You might will need to wrap your for loop in an async function for this to work. Just do `(async() { ...... the code of your loop ...... })();` to do that.